# WP Query to not return values in array

Tags: wordpress

I am using WP_Query to return one random post. I would like to use an updated session variable which contains a list of post for WP_Query to **not** return. How can I add this to the array or function?

This is my code

```
$args = array(
    'tag' => $_GET['Category'],
    'orderby' => 'rand',
    'posts_per_page'=>1
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution: post__not_in where $postid is an array.

```
$args = array(
    'tag' => $_GET['Category'],
    'orderby' => 'rand',
    'posts_per_page'=>1,
    'post__not_in' =>  $postid
);
```